# pure virtual called from destructor

Tags: c++, herencia

Estoy construyendo una pequeña jerarquía para una *cosita* personal. Son clases que encapsularan punteros a estructuras de una librería escrita en C. Estoy usando la clásica técnica [`pimpl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl).

<sub>**Nota**: la librería en C usa *herencia* en `struct` mediante el clásico método de definir macros con las variables-miembro y declarar las `struct` usando dichas macros, por lo que no es posible una relación de herencia desde C++. De ahí el uso de punteros `void *`.</sub>

La clase raiz de mi jerarquía es:

```
class TrivialPImpl {
public:
    ~TrivialPImpl( ) {
        if( m_pimpl ) {
            unlock( m_pimpl );
        }
    }
    TrivialPImpl( void *ptr = nullptr ) : m_pimpl( ptr ) { }
    TrivialPImpl( const TrivialPImpl &other ) = default;
    TrivialPImpl( TrivialPImpl &&other ) : m_pimpl( const_cast< void * >( other.m_pimpl ) ) {
        if( m_pimpl ) {
            m_pimpl = nullptr;
        }
    }

protected:
    virtual void unlock( void *ptr ) = 0;

private:
    void *m_pimpl;
};
```

Yo espero que se cumpla lo siguiente:

1. `TrivialPimpl::unlock( )` es una función virtual pura, no es posible instanciar de clases hija sin proporcionar un código para `unlock( )`.
2. Mientras no defina ningún destructor en ninguna clase hija, la llamada a un destructor (de cualquier hija) provocará la llamada a `TrivialPImpl::~TrivialPImpl( )`
3. Desde `TrivialPImpl::~TrivialPImpl( )` se llamará a `unlock( )`, que ejecutará el código correcto dependiente del tipo real de la instancia destruida.

Debido a esos puntos, entiendo que es imposible obtener un puntero a una instancia de una clase hija de `TrivialPImpl` **sin** que tenga implementada la función `unlock( )`, por lo que es igualmente imposible que desde el destructor de `TrivialPImpl` se llame a una versión de `unlock( )` sin cuerpo.

Sin embargo, el compilador me muestra 1 aviso:

> pure virtual ‘virtual void TrivialPImpl::unlock()’ called from destructor

- ¿ Es mi razonamiento correcto ? ¿ Se llamará siempre a la implementación correcta de `unlock( )` ?
- En caso positivo, ¿ Cual es el sentido de ese aviso del compilador ?
- En caso negativo, ¿ En que me estoy equivocando ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se mucho en c++ pero creo que esto pasa por la jerarquía al llamarse los destructores.

Te explico con un ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{
    ~A(){
        //unlock()
        std::cout <<"Destructor A"<< std::endl;
    }
    virtual void unlock() = 0;
};

struct B : public A{
    ~B(){
        std::cout <<"Destructor B"<< std::endl;
    }
    void unlock() override{
        std::cout <<"Unlock"<< std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    B b;    //Al acabar el main() se llamara al destructor
}
```

La salida del programa será:

```
Destructor B
Destructor A
```

Aquí podemos apreciar que el destructor de la clase que hereda siempre será invocado antes que el de la clase padre; por lo que al destruirse B, cuando se intente llamar al método unlock() en el destructor de la clase A, sólo encontrará la definición virtual de A, y de ahí el error de compilación.

[Se recomienda nunca llamar a funciones virtuales en los constructores y destructores](https://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html)

Del que podemos extraer:

> The same reasoning applies during destruction. Once a derived class
> destructor has run, the object's derived class data members assume
> undefined values, so C++ treats them as if they no longer exist. Upon
> entry to the base class destructor, the object becomes a base class
> object, and all parts of C++—virtual functions, dynamic_casts,
> etc.—treat it that way.